# How to report a crash when there isn't a .crash file

Tags: 11.04, unity, bug-reporting

I am suffering from a bug/crash in Natty, which I have logged in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/737928

The response I got back on my bug was a "provide us with a .crash file, or we won't look into it". Not very helpful really, but I can understand that the developers need something to work with. I have checked for this .crash file, which I can provide, but it isn't there.

So, my question is, what else can I provide/do in order to get this bug looked at and fixed?

It can't be a specific problem as it happens to both my 32bit laptop and my 64bit desktop, both being very different machines, and it is stopping me from connecting to my development & backup network machines so I can't do my work...

It turns out that I had to replicate the bug a number of times before I finally got promoted to report it by Apport. It would be nice, though, if there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find some of the Unity bug filing a bit brusque too, such as using "Incomplete" to mean "we haven't decided how to fix this yet" even though it is a real bug.

If you have a hang/crash bug, one good way to get some more data is to run `strace` on the process in question, with eg

```
strace -ff -o /tmp/unity.strace -p UNITY_PID
```

(after finding the right pid), then attach that file to the bug.  I can't promise they'll accept it but for things I work on that's often helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This can be frustrating as I've had to file a few bugs by hand using the advanced debugging procedures here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/FilingBugs

I was having a particularly bad crasher so I had to open the web page on my laptop (or you can print it out or something), then get it to crash, then follow the procedures and then file a bug and attach the log.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Apport - details on how to do this are found on the Ubuntu Wiki [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport)

Comment: That is my point though, Apport is enabled but it isn't picking up on the crash. Usually I'd get a dialog telling me that the system died, but not in this case.

Comment: Did you read through the how to guide at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport/DeveloperHowTo

Comment: That appears to be for application developers to get Apport reporting correctly, not end users who have nothing to do with the application's development.